# What is CRS:84 projection?

Tags: wms, wgs84

Does anybody know is `CRS:84` in WMS v.1.3.0 `getCapabalities` response is same projection as WGS84 <s>(EPSG:2180)</s>(EPSG:4326)?

And is `[westBoundLongitude],[eastBoundLongitude],[southBoundLatitude],[northBoundLatitude]` in `EX_GeographicBoundingBox` respectively equivalent with `[minx],[miny],[maxx],[maxy]` in earlier version of WMS response (1.1.1)?

Comment: [eastBoundLongitude] should be equivalent to [maxx], and [southBoundLatitude] to [miny], so take care for the order of the four bounds.

Comment: Is it supposed to be `getCapabilities`  instead of `getCapabalities`?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In regards to your first question, EPSG:2180 is a Polish projection based on Transverse Mercator. CRS:84 is equivalent to EPSG:4326 - ie, basic WGS84 degrees.

http://mapserver.org/ogc/wms_server.html#coordinate-systems-and-axis-orientation

Comment: yeah, I meant equivalent to WGS84 thanks for link! I was looking everywhere but I wasn't sure about that.

Answer (score 25):

Actually it's equivalent to EPSG:4326 but changing the axis from Lat-Long to Long-Lat. The standard EPSG:4326 is Lat-Long